# Logo and image on same row issue

Tags: html, css

Logo and image on the same row.But padding top only the issue.Check the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/6Rpkh/443/

```
 <img class='likeordislike' src='image'><h4 class='liketext'>Twitter</h4>
```

The issue is the text below the image. So I want to place into the middle of the image. Padding style not working on that

Answer (score 1):

First note that your image class is `likeordislike`, yet your selector is `likeordisklike` (with an extra `k`), so it will never apply. You'll also want to remove the `width` from it (to prevent stretching), and give it a taller `height`.

Now that the image is sorted, the text can be vertically aligned to the middle by:

- Giving it **[`display: inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)**
- Setting the **[`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)** equal to the height you're trying to align with
- Setting **[`vertical-align: middle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)**

This can be seen in the following:

```css
img.likeordislike {
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

h4.liketext {
  color: #F00;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<img class='likeordislike' src='data:image/png;base64,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'>
<h4 class='liketext'>Twitter</h4>
```